# What javascript library sets the _parsedUrl property on a request object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working with node/express/passport/ looking at code that attempts to use a request like:

`req._parsedUrl.pathname;`

I cannot figure out where this variable is coming from. Is this a canonical variable name that is set in a common .js library? It doesn't seem exposed in any headers.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`req._parsedUrl` is created by the [`parseurl` library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parseurl) which is used by Express' `Router` when [handling an incoming request](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/router/index.js#L203).

The `Router` doesn't actually intend to create `req._parsedUrl`. Instead `parseurl` creates the variable as a form of [optimization through caching](https://github.com/pillarjs/parseurl/blob/master/index.js#L48-L53).

If you want to use `req._parsedUrl.pathname` do the following instead in order to ensure that your server doesn't crash if `req._parsedUrl` is missing:

```
var parseUrl = require('parseurl');

function yourMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    var pathname = parseUrl(req).pathname;
    // Do your thing with pathname
}
```

`parseurl` will return `req._parsedUrl` if it already exists or if not it does the parsing for the first time. Now you get the `pathname` in a save way while still not parsing the url more than once.

Answer (score -2):

You can write a middleware to handle then set properties for req.

```
var myMiddleWare = function () {
   return function (req, res, next) {
       req._parsedUrl = 'SOME_THING';
       next()
   }
};

app.get('/', myMiddleWare, function (req, res) {
   console.log(req._parsedUrl); // SOME_THING
   res.end();
})
```

Express middleware document in [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)